# Using javascript or jQuery to hide all list elements after a specific one

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

What would be the quickest way to go through all of the list items in one unordered list and remove all of the items after a specified list item?

Example: Let's say the list will always contain an item with the text "Hobbies." The javascript bit will have to find that item and remove all of the li items after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) and [`.nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

```
$('li:contains("Hobbies.")').nextAll().hide();
```

Comment: nextAll! Awesome. I'll have to research that more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Grab your item using the `:contains` selector to look for "Hobbies". Then you can grab all `li` items after it with `nextAll()` and `remove()` them.

Answer (score 1):

This will hide all the li elements after the specific one

```
$('li').filter(function(index) { return $(this).text() === "Hobbies"; }).nextAll().hide();
```

Comment: Could you provide some info on contains vs. filter? Thanks!

Comment: contains will return items if the specific text is found anywhere within the text. For example 'I have Hobbies.' will be selected if you use contains. Filter gives you option to write your own function.